# Proving $\sqrt[6]{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Can someine please tell me quickly how to prove that $\sqrt[6]{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ ? I have an exam in a about an hour and I can't figure this out (my idea was to prove it indirectly, but playing around with $$\sqrt[6]{2}=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$$ with rational $a,b$ doesn't lead me anywhere...)

Comment: Why are you looking at $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$? Do you believe this is the general form of an element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: @ChrisEagle But isn't that the case ? Since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ we should have $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, which tells me that is of the above form...

Comment: Can you express $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2=\sqrt[3]{4}$ as $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$ for rational $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles No, I don't think so. But how does that relate to the above ?

Comment: @user47580: $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$...

Comment: @user47580: More generally, the degree of a field extension $L/K$ is (by definition) the dimension of $L$ when it is considered as a vector space over $K$. If you believe that any element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ can be written as $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$ for rational $a$ and $b$, then that means you believe the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is 2, because there is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space with two elements.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ah, I understand now...thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sqrt[6]{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, then you would have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$. The $\supseteq$ containment is clear, and since $(\sqrt[6]{2})^2=\sqrt[3]{2}$, we would have $\sqrt[3]{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$ giving the other containment.

But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, whereas $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$ is a $6$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, since the minimal polynomials of the adjoined elements are $x^3-2$ and $x^6-2$, respectively, both irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ as they are $2$-Eisentstein. So this is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt[6]{2}$ is a root of $x^6-2$. This is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein, so $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$ is a six-dimensional extension. Similarly, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a three-dimensional extension. Thus the former is not contained in the latter.

Comment: What this problem really boils down to is $6 \nmid 3$.